# Checking Elasticsearch Heap Size

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch

How can I check the heap size that is assigned to Elasticsearch engine, is there a way to check it using URL API ? And can I use NEST to check it?

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

In a clustered environment, heap settings can be queried as :

```
curl -sS  "localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?h=heap*&v"
```

Eg:

```
curl -sS  "localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?h=heap*&v"
heap.current heap.percent heap.max
     321.1mb           32  989.8mb
     424.1mb           42  989.8mb
     280.3mb           28  989.8mb
```

This can also be checked from the ps results, though it will only shed light on the min-max values.

```
~#ps aux | grep --color=auto -i Xms
elastic  6020  0.0  0.0  12788   936 pts/4    S+   04:24   0:00 grep --color=auto -i Xms elastic+  7218
0.6  9.5 5001220 1565112 ?     Ssl  Jun24   5:14 /usr/bin/java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch.WoiU4NhH -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/elasticsearch -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/elasticsearch/hs_err_pid%p.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -Xloggc:/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=32 -XX:GCLogFileSize=64m -Xms1g -Xmx1g -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch -Des.distribution.flavor=default -Des.distribution.type=deb -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch -p /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid --quiet
```

where -Xms is the minheap and -Xmx is maxheap configured.

Comment: cool, the REST API works fine on latest ES (7.14) too.

Answer (score 12):

use `GET _nodes/stats`

Then look at the following in the return /jvm/mem/heap_committed_in_bytes

Comment: what should i run to use GET ? i am using windows

Comment: that command makes all nodes in my cluster to crash! The `/_nodes` endpoint works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As per the online [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html), the default heap size is 1 Gb unless you explicitly mention in the Environment Variable [ES_HEAP_SIZE]

> The default installation of Elasticsearch is configured with a 1 GB
>   heap. For just about every deployment, this number is far too small.
>   If you are using the default heap values, your cluster is probably
>   configured incorrectly.
>
> There are two ways to change the heap size in Elasticsearch. The
>   easiest is to set an environment variable called ES_HEAP_SIZE. When
>   the server process starts, it will read this environment variable and
>   set the heap accordingly. As an example, you can set it via the
>   command line as follows:
>
> export ES_HEAP_SIZE=10g Alternatively, you can pass in the heap size
>   via a command-line argument when starting the process, if that is
>   easier for your setup:
>
> ./bin/elasticsearch -Xmx10g -Xms10g
>
> Ensure that the min (Xms) and max (Xmx) sizes are the same to prevent
>   the heap from resizing at runtime, a very costly process.
>
> Generally, setting the ES_HEAP_SIZE environment variable is preferred
>   over setting explicit -Xmx and -Xms values.

Answer (score 0):

This is a new account so I couldn't comment on jhilden's answer. His answer is correct but to answer your comment I use Postman which is a chrome app. It's very easy to use and has been ideal for me whilst working with Elasticsearch.

Putting the following in postman and hitting send does the job!

> http://localhost:9200/_nodes/stats

review the results and look for the "jvm" block. Here is what is returned when I run it on a default elasticsearch setup:

```
"jvm": {
    "timestamp": 1477474766408,
    "uptime_in_millis": 1309586,
    "mem": {
      **"heap_used_in_bytes": 87134248**,
      "heap_used_percent": 8,
      "heap_committed_in_bytes": 259522560,
      "heap_max_in_bytes": 1038876672,
      "non_heap_used_in_bytes": 56166992,
      "non_heap_committed_in_bytes": 57348096,
```