# Elasticsearch response time - strange values

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm querying simple Elasticsearch index with house numbers data.

```
".house-numbers": {
    "mappings": {
      "house-number": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "text",
            "index_options": "docs"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Then I'm querying data like POST http request

Request url

```
http://localhost:9200/.house-numbers/housenumber/_search
```

Headers:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 55
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

Request body:

```
{
  "size": 30,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "value": {
        "query": "2 3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Request returns data in 10ms - 30ms and everything works fine. Elasticsearch reponse parameter took is small in all cases 3-5ms.

When I change size in request body to `"size": 35` response time has suddenly 500ms. Took parameter from Elasticsearch is the same. There are no special characters and size of response is very similar.

I tried many clients NEST, Postman, Fiddler to do these requests, every client has the same behaviour.

Setting of my elasticsearch contains only

```
http.compression : true
http.compression_level : 9
```

Setting of my jvm

```
"jvm": {
  "timestamp": 1478108615141,
  "uptime_in_millis": 17150141,
  "mem": {
    "heap_used_in_bytes": 1384307624,
    "heap_used_percent": 66,
    "heap_committed_in_bytes": 2077753344,
    "heap_max_in_bytes": 2077753344,
    "non_heap_used_in_bytes": 96403904,
    "non_heap_committed_in_bytes": 101502976,
    "pools": {
      "young": {
        "used_in_bytes": 324358632,
        "max_in_bytes": 558432256,
        "peak_used_in_bytes": 558432256,
        "peak_max_in_bytes": 558432256
      },
      "survivor": {
        "used_in_bytes": 69730304,
        "max_in_bytes": 69730304,
        "peak_used_in_bytes": 69730304,
        "peak_max_in_bytes": 69730304
      },
      "old": {
        "used_in_bytes": 990220848,
        "max_in_bytes": 1449590784,
        "peak_used_in_bytes": 1190046816,
        "peak_max_in_bytes": 1449590784
      }...
```

I tried different versions of elasticsearch
I tried different settings - turn off http.compression, change compression_level
I tried another hosts for elasticsearch

I have no idea what can cause this problem and I can't continue with my work.
Any idea where to look or how to proceed?

Comment: If you run that query 10-20 times does it get faster?  ElasticSearch automatically moved data in and out of the cache as needed so sometimes the first query is slow but subsequent queries are very fast.

Comment: Also, how much memory do you have pinned to the JVM?  [Get that info here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100072/checking-elastic-search-heap-size/32107177#32107177)

Comment: @jhilden It isn't getting faster after requests but sometimes one request lasts e.g. 8ms and then again ten requests last 500ms.

Comment: @jhilden I added JVM settings to the question

Comment: Try to use [Profile API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-profile.html) in the query to get more information about the execution

Comment: @Allan Sene I tried it but there is no problem. On the Elasticsearch side it looks correctly. I see the problem in the response transferring or compression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course problem was not in elasticsearch but in the http communication, especially when http compression was turned on

Hints to remove delays

- close fiddler
- disable firewall and anti-virus software
- close all programs that possibly can intercept http communication